# Type converter for Class and Enum

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a `class Claim` and an `Enum Role`.

I often need to convert `Claim` to `Role` or the opposite.

And usually I also convert `List<Claim>` to `List<Role>` or the opposite.

In this case Role is the following enum:

```
public enum Role {
  Leader = 1,
  Editor = 2
} // Role
```

Note: include only 2 items for sake of simplicity.

Then a Claim is a class with two properties:

```
public class Claim {
  public String Type { get; set; }
  public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

1. Converting `Role` to `Claim`:

   `Claim.Type = "Role" and Claim.Value={Role Text} (Example: Leader)`
2. Converting `Role` to `Claim`:

Only applied to `Claims` which Type is `Role`.

In these cases the conversion is the inverse if (1)

I am not sure if a Type converter is the best solution.

But I would like to somehow make these conversions as simple as possible.

Something reusable because I often need to do this conversions.

Maybe an extension? A helper? The type converter?

Comment: Without any code, I don't think anybody is going to be able to answer you.

Comment: Can you add some code that shows how you translate them back and forth?

Comment: I just updated my post and added code.

Answer (score 6):

A TypeConverter is not what you want, it tends to be far more intensive in its implementation, more obtuse, and allows design-time capabilities that you don't seem to need. If your goal is to allow someone using these objects to move between the two with minimal code required, you can define an implicit conversion (or an explicit one, if you want to force the cast syntax).

```
public class Claim
{
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Role(Claim claim)
    {
        return (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), claim.Value);
    }
    public static implicit operator Claim(Role role)
    {
        return new Claim() { Type = "Role", Value = role.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Doing that would allow the following code to work because it would make use of the conversion you've defined.

```
Claim claim = Role.Leader;
Role role = claim;
```

**Update**

You've said in your comment that you can't touch the Claim class. The simplest way would probably be extension methods, then.

```
static class ClaimExtensions
{
    public static Role ToRole(this Claim claim)
    {
        return (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), claim.Value);
    }
    public static Claim ToClaim(this Role role)
    {
        return new Claim() { Type = "Role", Value = role.ToString() };
    }
}
```

That would mean a method call, but it would be fairly straightforward for developers to use and understand.

```
Claim claim = Role.Leader.ToClaim();
Role role = claim.ToRole();
```

Comment: That is a nice ... But in case I am not able do anything inside the Claim class ... It is a .NET class. Maybe an extension is the way.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create and use a Type converter for this?

You just read [How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "fetch" or create one based on the value of another, you can to two things:

1 - To go from an enum to a class, I would use a Factory Method.  Pass in a enum and return a class of the appropriate type.

2 - I would change the claim "Type" property to an enum of type Role, so that you can instantly retrieve the enum value associated with the caim.

If that cannot work since "Type" can possibly hold values not in the Role enum, then I would add a property possibly nullable of type Role.